# PHP 2D Array - Syntax issue

Tags: php

I have a 2D Array. If I do `print_r($equities[0])` , I get:

```
Array
(
    [No.] => 1
    ["Ticker"] => "CAFE"
    ["Company"] => "iPath Pure Beta Coffee ETN"
    ["Price"] => 27.59
)
```

I then try to print the 'Ticker' for the first element like this:

```
echo $equities[0]["Ticker"];
```

But, it does not print anything. How can I print the ticker?

Comment: Can you post how you created the array with the PHP code please?

Comment: $ php -r '$equities = array(0 => array("ticker" => "CAFE")); echo $equities[0]["ticker"];'
gives CAFE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got quotes in your dump, which means the quotes are encoded into the array key names as well (e.g. double quoted).

Try

```
echo $equities[0]['"Ticker"'];
                  ^        ^
```

note the extra single quotes.

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me understand how I might have known that those single quotes where there when I could not see them?

Comment: Anytime you have trouble accessing something in an array you know should be there, you should whip out print_r/var_dump and see what really is there.

Answer (score 0):

What the "No." key? Try to see all array (print_r($equities)).